# Prove that every countable and $\aleph_0$-saturated model is a universal model.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm trying to prove the title. My textbook says the proof is similar to an exercise which asks you to prove that a countable and atomic model of a complete theory is prime. I can do the exercise, but I don't see how to adapt this proof. Here is my proof of the exercise.

Suppose a model $\mathcal{A}$ of $T$ is atomic and countable and let $\mathcal{M}$ be any model of $T$. Let $a_1, a_2, \dots$ be an enumeration of $\mathcal{A}$. We want to construct a mapping $\pi \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{M}$ such that, for all formulas $\varphi(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$, $\mathcal{A} \models \varphi(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \iff \mathcal{M} \models \varphi(\pi(a_1), \pi(a_2), \dots, \pi(a_n))$.

Proceed by induction. For $n = 0$, this holds because $T$ is complete. Suppose the statement holds for $n$. Let $\psi$ be the principal formula of $\textrm{tp}_\mathcal{A}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n + 1})$ which exists because $\mathcal{A}$ is atomic. Then $\mathcal{A} \models \psi(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{n + 1})$, so $\mathcal{A} \models \exists x \ \psi(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, x)$, so $\mathcal{M} \models \exists x \ \psi(\pi(a_1), \pi(a_2), \dots, \psi(a_n), x)$ by induction hypothesis. Then there exists some $m$ such that $\mathcal{M} \models \psi(\pi(a_1), \pi(a_2), \dots, \pi(a_n), m)$. Let $\pi(a_{n + 1}) := m$. Since $\psi$ was principal, $\mathcal{M}$ models any formula $\phi$ of these variables if $\mathcal{A}$ does. Since it was the principal formula of a complete type, the converse also holds. Therefore, $\pi$ is an elementary embedding and $\mathcal{A}$ is prime.

It seems like the proof could be easily adapted if I could show that, if $\mathcal{M}$ was an $\aleph_0$-saturated and countable model, then any countable model $\mathcal{A}$ could be embedded into $\mathcal{M}$. Then I could use the fact the model is saturated to show that the embedding was elementary.

However, as it is I'm not sure how to embed the model. For instance, let $a_1, a_2, \dots$ be an enumeration of $\mathcal{A}$. What should $a_1$ map to? It's tempting to map it to some random element, but this shouldn't work intuitively, for example if the element we're mapping to witnesses some constant of the language, but $a_1$ doesn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: You map it to something of the same type.

Comment: "Then I could use the fact the model is saturated to show that the embedding was elementary." How's that? Not every embedding into a saturated model is elementary! If you want to construct an elementary embedding, you had better map $a_1$ to some element of the saturated model realizing the complete type of $a_1$. Hmm, how could we ever find an element realizing a given complete type in a saturated model...?

Comment: If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of a theory $T$, I don't think I can know that $\textrm{tp}_{\mathcal{A}}(a_1)$ is a type of $\textrm{Th}(\mathcal{M})$, since I can't prove the type will still be consistent in this theory. Although now that I wrote that, I realize that the problem is a bit ambiguous when it comes to that, does the title even hold if I'm trying to prove $\mathcal{M}$ is a universal model of an arbitrary theory $T$ that it models, not necessarily $\textrm{Th}(\mathcal{M})$?

Comment: @zaq If $T$ is complete and $M\models T$, then $T=\mathrm{Th}(M)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Right, although that wasn't mentioned in the problem. It said to prove $\mathcal{M}$ was universal in "its theory". I guess this means $\textrm{Th}(\mathcal{M})$ and I just misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, I would interpret "its theory" to mean "the theory of $M$", i.e. $\mathrm{Th}(M)$.